# Vue make const inside method available in template

Tags: vue.js

I have a RoleIndex component where I import a Roles component in which I import a RoleItem  component. So the RoleIndex component shows a list of roles. Below I want to show the details of role selected, based on the item clicked on list. Basically like tabs.

In other words I need to send role.id from RoleItem to RoleIndex and retrieve the correct object to be shown in template.

For each RoleItem I created a button which sends role.id to Index component with $emit.

In RoleIndex I have created a method:

```js
showRole(id) {
  this.$http.get('roles.json').then(res => {
    const data = res.data;
    const role = data.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.id === id;
    }).pop();
    console.log(role);
  })
}
```

which succesfully shows in console a json for the role selected.

Now I need to show row details in template like {{role.name}}.

But role is not available in template. How do I make it available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the response data to Vue's reactivity system. The idiomatic way to this is to set some property on the instance that has been set using the returned object from the `data` factory.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      role: null,
    };
  },
};
```

`role` can now be used *reactively*, i.e. `{{ role.name }}` in templates or in computed properties. You can use some conditional logic to only show `role` when it is truthy.

Once you have sent the request and received the response you can simply do:

```js
this.role = data.filter((obj) => obj.id === id).pop();
```

And the reactivity system will take care of the rest.